# trying to close popover - python - selenium - Glassdoor

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to close a popover while scraping Glassdoor for jobs [It keeps popping up from time to time - need to close it every time].. I've tried quite a few things
Tried closing it by looking for the close button. Please help !

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("SVG_Inline modal_closeIcon").click()
```

Tried looking for a ElementClickInterceptedException when the bot couldn't click on the next company, and everywhere else there was a click

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "SVG_Inline-svg modal_closeIcon-svg")))
            element.click()
```

This is the website:
https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Job/web-developer-jobs-SRCH_KO0,13.htm

This is the complete code:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementClickInterceptedException, StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



def get_jobs(keyword, num_jobs, verbose, place):
'''Gathers jobs as a dataframe, scraped from Glassdoor'''

#Initializing the webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

#Uncomment the line below if you'd like to scrape without a new Chrome window every time.
#options.add_argument('headless')

#Change the path to where chromedriver is in your home folder.
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/omersakarya/Documents/GitHub/scraping-glassdoor-selenium/chromedriver", options=options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 1000)

url = "https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Job/web-developer-jobs-SRCH_KO0,13.htm"

driver.get(url)
jobs = []
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()
time.sleep(3)



while len(jobs) < num_jobs:  #If true, should be still looking for new jobs.
    job_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jl")  #jl for Job Listing. These are the buttons we're going to click.
    try:
        for job_button in job_buttons:
            if len(jobs) >= num_jobs:
                break
            print("Progress: {}".format("" + str(len(jobs)) + "/" + str(num_jobs)))
            job_button.click()
            collected_successfully = False

            while not collected_successfully:
                try:
                    company_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="employerName"]').text
                    location = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="location"]').text
                    job_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "title")]').text
                    job_description = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="jobDescriptionContent desc"]').text
                    collected_successfully = True
                except:
                    time.sleep(5)

            try:
                    #salary_estimate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="gray salary"]').text
                    salary_estimate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="HeroHeaderModule"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/span').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                    salary_estimate = -1 #You need to set a "not found value. It's important."

            try:
                    rating = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="rating"]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                    rating = -1 #You need to set a "not found value. It's important."

                #Printing for debugging
            if verbose:
                print("Job Title: {}".format(job_title))
                print("Salary Estimate: {}".format(salary_estimate))
                print("Job Description: {}".format(job_description[:500]))
                print("Rating: {}".format(rating))
                print("Company Name: {}".format(company_name))
                print("Location: {}".format(location))

                #Going to the Company tab...
                #clicking on this:
                #<div class="tab" data-tab-type="overview"><span>Company</span></div>
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="tab" and @data-tab-type="overview"]').click()
                try:
                            #<div class="infoEntity">
                            #    <label>Headquarters</label>
                            #    <span class="value">San Francisco, CA</span>
                            #</div>
                    headquarters = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Headquarters"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    headquarters = -1

                try:
                    size = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Size"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    size = -1

                try:
                    founded = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Founded"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):
                    founded = -1

                try:
                    type_of_ownership = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Type"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    type_of_ownership = -1

                try:
                    industry = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Industry"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    industry = -1

                try:
                    sector = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Sector"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    sector = -1

                try:
                    revenue = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Revenue"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    revenue = -1

                try:
                    competitors = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Competitors"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    competitors = -1



            except (NoSuchElementException,ElementClickInterceptedException,StaleElementReferenceException):  #Rarely, some job postings do not have the "Company" tab.
                  if NoSuchElementException:
                      time.sleep(1)       
                      headquarters = -1
                      size = -1
                      founded = -1
                      type_of_ownership = -1
                      industry = -1
                      sector = -1
                      revenue = -1
                      competitors = -1
                  else:
                      driver.find_element_by_class_name("selected").click()
                      driver.find_element_by_class_name("SVG_Inline modal_closeIcon").click()
                      element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "SVG_Inline-svg modal_closeIcon-svg")))
                      element.click()
                      pass




            if verbose:
                print("Headquarters: {}".format(headquarters))
                print("Size: {}".format(size))
                print("Founded: {}".format(founded))
                print("Type of Ownership: {}".format(type_of_ownership))
                print("Industry: {}".format(industry))
                print("Sector: {}".format(sector))
                print("Revenue: {}".format(revenue))
                print("Competitors: {}".format(competitors))
                print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")

            jobs.append({"Job Title" : job_title,
            "Salary Estimate" : salary_estimate,
            "Job Description" : job_description,
            "Rating" : rating,
            "Company Name" : company_name,
            "Location" : location,
            "Headquarters" : headquarters,
            "Size" : size,
            "Founded" : founded,
            "Type of ownership" : type_of_ownership,
            "Industry" : industry,
            "Sector" : sector,
            "Revenue" : revenue,
            "Competitors" : competitors})
                        #You might 
                        #time.sleep(0.5)

    except (ElementClickInterceptedException, StaleElementReferenceException):
        alertObj = driver.switch_to.alert
        alertObj.accept()
        alertObj.dismiss()
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("selected").click()
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("SVG_Inline modal_closeIcon").click()
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "SVG_Inline-svg modal_closeIcon-svg")))
        element.click()
        pass




                    #add job to jobs

            #Clicking on the "next page" button
           # try:
             #   driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//li[@class="page"]//a').click()
           # except NoSuchElementException:
             #   print("Scraping terminated before reaching target number of jobs. Needed {}, got {}.".format(num_jobs, len(jobs)))
            #    break
           # time.sleep(5)

    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//li[@class="next"]//a').click()
    except (ElementClickInterceptedException):
        #print("Scraping terminated before reaching target number of jobs. Needed {}, got {}.".format(num_jobs, len(jobs)))
            driver.find_element_by_class_name("selected").click()
            driver.find_element_by_class_name("SVG_Inline modal_closeIcon").click()
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "SVG_Inline-svg modal_closeIcon-svg")))
            element.click()
            element.text
            pass
        #break


return pd.DataFrame(jobs)  #This line converts the dictionary object into a pandas DataFrame.


df = gs.get_jobs(keyword, num_jobs, False, place)
```

Trying to get rid of this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJF5E.png)
[Screenshot of the element I need to close and continue with the loop][2]